# Backup files are lost while backing up to Azure URL from SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, azure-blob-storage

I have a job script like this which should backup SQL Server 2016 dbs to Azure blob storage with storage key credential. Usually it works fine, but sometimes a few backups are lost (I mean there is no backup file on the storage account) and I do not get any kind or job failure or errors on job log file. Dbs are just skipped. I have noticed that when backup job overlaps maintenance procedures this happens quite often when I have changed times it happened once a month or less. But I am not sure that maintenance(index maint, dbcc, stats update) is the reason for this anomaly.

I would like to know whether had you any prior experience like this and may know what is the core reason?

The interesting part is that I have restore verifyonly which also just skips databases. It does not try to restore those dbs that's why I do not get fail errors, just skips

```
DECLARE @dbname sysname
DECLARE @path nvarchar(120)
DECLARE @credential sysname = 'BackupStorageCredential'
DECLARE @date nvarchar(250) = CAST( GETDATE() AS Date ) 
SET @path = N'[my_storage_url]'

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name FROM sys.databases
WHERE name IN ('db1','db2','db3')
OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname   
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
    DECLARE @query_backupToAzBLOB   NVARCHAR(max)
    DECLARE @query_verify   NVARCHAR(max)

    SET @query_backupTOAzBLOB = 'BACKUP DATABASE [' + @dbname + '] TO  URL =''' + @path + @dbname + '/' + @dbname + '_' + @date +'.bak'' 
                            WITH CREDENTIAL = ''' + @credential + ''',NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME =''' + @dbname + ''',
                            NOSKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION,  STATS = 10, CHECKSUM'
    EXEC (@query_backupTOAzBLOB)
    SET @query_verify = 'RESTORE VERIFYONLY  FROM URL =''' + @path + @dbname + '/' + @dbname + '_' + @date +'.bak'' 
                            WITH  CREDENTIAL = ''' + @credential + ''',  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5'
    EXEC(@query_verify)
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname   
END   
CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: I would suggest to add logging into the script. It will help you to see when and which part of the code is omitting/failing.

Comment: @AndreySamykin I have logged the script execution results. There was no backup operation for mentioned dbs nor verify only operations. They are just omitted while I can see detailed info for other dbs

Comment: You should log the results from your query against sys.databases, my initial feeling is that the databases just aren't there when you are trying to run the backup commands (and so the backup command isn't even attempted)

Comment: ^...or they could be in an invalid state for backing up, such as "recovering" or "offline".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with your code.

1. Your primary issue: using a non-`STATIC` cursor over `sys.databases` [can cause databases to be skipped.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/261603/220697)
2. You have SQL injection vulnerabilities. You could quote all the parameters using `QUOTENAME`, but `BACKUP` actually allows everything to be parameterized anyway, so you can actually execute `BACKUP` directly using parameters, there is no need for dynamic SQL.

```sql
DECLARE @dbname sysname;
DECLARE @path nvarchar(120) = N'[my_storage_url]';
DECLARE @credential sysname = 'BackupStorageCredential';
DECLARE @date nvarchar(250) = CAST( GETDATE() AS Date );

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY STATIC READ_ONLY FOR
SELECT name FROM sys.databases
WHERE name IN ('db1','db2','db3')
  AND state_desc = 'ONLINE';

OPEN db_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname; 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN

    DECLARE @fullPath nvarchar(255) = @path + @dbname + '/' + @dbname + '_' + @date +'.bak';

    BACKUP DATABASE @dbname
    TO URL = @fullPath 
    WITH CREDENTIAL = @credential, NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME = @dbname,
        NOSKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION, STATS = 10, CHECKSUM;

    RESTORE VERIFYONLY
    FROM URL = @fullPath
    WITH CREDENTIAL = @credential, FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 5;

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname; 
END;
CLOSE db_cursor; 
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;
```

You  should probably consider appending the time to the URL also, as executing this twice will fail.

Comment: Appending to a BLOB is not supported, so this will fail on re-run.  Should probably be WITH FORMAT, or append the time into the blob name.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Agreed (this code was from OP), although the filename is unique by database name and date, so it's only a problem if executed twice on the same day. Key point is that `BACKUP` and `RESTORE` can be fully parameterized, for some reason people insist on using dynamic SQL

Answer (score 4):

Declaring a cursor over sys.databases is a classic. Sometimes, for whatever reason, some databases are skipped.

Change the cursor type to STATIC and you will likely see that this doesn't happen. To be certain that this is the reason, log to a table of yours using an INSERT inside the cursor to be absolutely certain that the database name was returned (or not) from the cursor query. I.e., rule out all backup related question marks.

While at it, you might want to add a condition for the database to be online. Here's an example from my sp_dbinfo procedure:

```
DECLARE db CURSOR STATIC FOR SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE state_desc = 'ONLINE'
```