Most efficient way to determine if a SQL Server database is using Read Committed Snapshot?
The conventional way to determine if a SQL Server is using read committed snapshot is a query similar to the following:
SELECT is_read_committed_snapshot_on 
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE database_id = db_id()

At present our system runs this query for each new connection it establishes (which it should not, but that's a different problem), but the above query is actually quite slow. It can take up to 8 milliseconds.
Looking at the query plan shows a substantial power of work being done to achieve the above.
Is there a more efficient way to determine this information, or should I just resign myself to trying to reduce the number of times I run this query instead?

Related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/261540/cursoring-over-sys-databases-skips-databases

The execution plan for
SELECT is_read_committed_snapshot_on 
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE database_id = db_id()

Contains a lot of outer join operations that appear surplus to requirements. Presumably they can't be optimised out as the optimiser can't be sure if the joins return more than one row and would change the row count returned.

Adding a DISTINCT removes these from the plan
SELECT DISTINCT is_read_committed_snapshot_on 
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE database_id = db_id()



Cool, but silly that it's necessary, no? Like, surely the optimizer knows that sys.databases.database_id is unique and so there can never be more than one row returned in the result set meaning that select and select distinct are logically equivalent.

@BenThul it knows that the id is unique in sysdbreg but it needs appropriate unique indexes for the base tables being joined onto/ metadata for the TVFs that guarantee they will only return at most one row from their joins. syssingleobjrefs has unique indexes on both class, depid, depsubid and indepid,class,indepsubid,depid,depsubid but the predicate in the execution plan against [master].[sys].[syssingleobjrefs] (as also shown in sp_helptext 'sys.databases') is just on depid, class so misses depsubid - so that needs to be preserved in the plan.

I can look later, but in this particular case, is there ever a value for depsubid when the class is whatever represents a database? If so, could the query in sys.databases have an additional predicate placed onto it (e.g. depsubid is null) such that the unique index can be used?

@BenThul - sys.databases is documented to only return one row per database so I presume in reality that predicate can never return more than one row. But currently the base tables are missing anything that will guarantee that to the optimiser. I doubt many people are doing this type of query at a rate that it will  make any noticeable difference
